# Getting checkbox status inside a view

Tags: java, android, checkbox

I have a layout which is being used as a template for a view. This view is being spawned multiple times and I want to access the values of some checkboxes which are part of the view.

This is my xml template:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/motor_block"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="30dp"
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:background="@drawable/motor_shape">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|left"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:text="Motor" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:tag="A"
    android:text="A" />
   <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:tag="B"
    android:text="B" />
      <CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/checkBox3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:tag="C"
    android:text="C" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText1"
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    android:maxLength="2" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>
```

I cant get the status doing

```
    CheckBox A = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
```

because it will get the status of the checkbox of the first view that was spawned.

Any ideas of how to get the status?

**EDIT**

I defined it:

```
    HashMap boxes = new HashMap();
```

Then I added the CheckBox with the view as a key:

```
    boxes.put(iv,(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
```

But when I do this:

```
    CheckBox A = boxes.get(v);
```

I get this:   *Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to CheckBox*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`HashMap` should be used with generics in new code. It's designed to be backwards-compatible with versions of Java that didn't support generics, but this is how you should make a new one (this has the added benefit of solving your casting problem):

```
HashMap<Integer, CheckBox> map = new HashMap<Integer, CheckBox>();
map.put(1, (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
...
CheckBox a = map.get(1);
```

You could also key on `String` or any other `Object` you need to.

Note how @Ascorbin created the list using generics in their suggestion as well.

**Edit**

To address your comment:

First, don't make a separate map for each checkbox; make one map to hold them all:

```
HashMap<Integer, CheckBox> map = new HashMap<Integer, CheckBox>();
map.put(1, (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1));
map.put(2, (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2));
...
CheckBox a = map.get(1);
CheckBox b = map.get(2);
```

To deal with the view being instantiated multiple times, you have 2 options:

1. Make your own custom `View` subclass that internally holds one of these maps and keep a reference to each instance of the view you create. Then, when you need a specific checkbox that's tied to a specific view, you can do something like the following:

   ```
   CheckBox a = myView.getCheckBoxMap().get(1);
   ```
2. (More self-contained, but worse design imo) Create an ugly data structure in your `Activity` like the following:

   ```
   HashMap<View, HashMap<Integer, CheckBox>> mainMap = new HashMap<View, HashMap<Integer, CheckBox>>();
   ```

   Then when you're instantiating the views:

   ```
   View view1 = createFirstView();
   CheckBox a = (CheckBox)view1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
   CheckBox b = (CheckBox)view1.findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
   HashMap<Integer, CheckBox> view1Map = new HashMap<Integer, CheckBox>();
   view1Map.put(1, a);
   view1Map.put(2, b);
   mainMap.put(view1, view1Map);
   // rinse and repeat for every instantiated view, changing the variables each time - ie, view2/view2Map, etc.
   ```

Comment: I used HashMap, I got it to work with independent maps for each box but all the CheckBoxes correspond to the first View which was spawned, any other solution?

Comment: Check the edit to my post; it turned out too long to put in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Make yourself an ArrayList or HashMap that contains references to all the checkboxes, then you can check/uncheck them later on.

```
ArrayList<CheckBox> boxes = new ArrayList<CheckBox>();
```

Everytime you create a view from your Layout you do

```
CheckBox A = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
boxes.add(A);
```

You can then later on do

```
boxes.get(5).setChecked(true);
```

You just have to think how you get the right index or you can use a HashMap and use keys.

Comment: I tried using HashMap but it is not working, can you put an example?

Comment: How about you post what you have tried and why / what isn't working.

Comment: 1. See space pope's answer on using generics. 2. If you have more than one checkbox in your view (which you have in your XML) you can't use the view as a key because keys in HashMaps are unique, I suggest you use integers as keys instead.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
CheckBox A = (CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox1);
.
.
.
if(boxes.get(v).isChecked()){
    //do something
}
else{
    //do another thing
}
```